# Multiple Sumifs excel into DAX

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, sumifs, powerbi-desktop

I am currently using Power BI as my organization is shifting towards it for the better visuals but they should have mentioned the complexity of the DAX :)

I have some multiple sumifs in an excel file that I cannot under anyway transform into Power BI using DAX

Here is the table I conducted in excel from raw data in another sheet:

[image]

and here is the code in the cells:

**Red Arrow code:**

```
=IFERROR((SUMIFS(ID_600!$E:$E,ID_600!$D:$D,"sick hours paid",ID_600!$A:$A,K$18)+SUMIFS(ID_600!$E:$E,ID_600!$D:$D,"sick hours unpaid",ID_600!$A:$A,K$18))/SUMIFS(ID_600!$E:$E,ID_600!$D:$D,"regular hours",ID_600!$A:$A,K$18),NA())
```

- Column A in sheet ID_600 have a date data and it is compared summed if it is equals to 11/5/2018

**Blue Arrow code:**

```
=IFERROR((SUMIFS(ID_600!$E$1:$E$5056,ID_600!$D$1:$D$5056,"sick hours paid",ID_600!$A$1:$A$5056,K$18,ID_600!$C$1:$C$5056,$A$23)+SUMIFS(ID_600!$E$1:$E$5056,ID_600!$D$1:$D$5056,"sick hours unpaid",ID_600!$A$1:$A$5056,K$18,ID_600!$C$1:$C$5056,$A$23))/SUMIFS(ID_600!$E$1:$E$5056,ID_600!$D$1:$D$5056,"regular hours",ID_600!$A$1:$A$5056,K$18,ID_600!$C$1:$C$5056,$A$23),NA())
```

- Column A in sheet ID_600 have a date data and it is compared summed if it is equals to 11/5/2018, in addition to summing if Column "In"(A23) matches the data in Column C in sheet ID_600

And after figuring out the DAX code, I will see what I can do to transform that using visualizations.

Sample file for raw data: https://ufile.io/lfddf

*edited 2

Comment: Perhaps include row/column headers in image.

Comment: added a new picture

Comment: I mean is the row 1 row 2? column A column B?

Comment: adjusted again :)]

Comment: The DAX you are asking for will work on the raw data. We can help you better if you provide a sample of that data. Also explain what the percentage values in your  pivottable mean.

Comment: calculating sickness rates for departments (In/Out/S/I) which is mainly: (sick hours paid + sick hours unpaid) / (regular hours) and a sample file is attached now.

Comment: the sample raw file: https://ufile.io/lfddf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DAX can be tricky, but in this case the DAX expressions are simpler than the excelformulas. To create something like your pivottable in a matrix visual, create the following three measures:

```
Total Sick Hours =
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'table'[hours] ),
    OR ( 'table'[type] = "Sick Hours Paid", 'table'[type] = "Sick Hours Unpaid" ))

Total Regular Hours = CALCULATE( SUM ( 'table'[hours] ), 'table'[type] = "Regular Hours" )

% Sick hours of Regular hours = DIVIDE( [Total Sick Hours], [Total Regular Hours], 0 )
```

Then create a matrix visual and put `dep` on Rows, `Date` on Columns and `% Sick hours of Regular hours` in Values. Format the `% Sick hours of Regular hours` as a perecentage (select the measure in the Fields pane and click % on the Modeling tab).

The result should look something like this:

[image]